# Adjust Google's Word2Vec loaded with Gensim to your vocabulary and then create the embedding vector

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim, embedding

I was wondering how can I limited the Google's Word2Vec to my vocabulary.
Google's Word2 vec link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit?usp=sharing

This is what I have:

```
import gensim

# Load Google's pre-trained Word2Vec model.
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('./model/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(my_vocabulary), 300))
```

where my vocabulary is a list of unique words in my corpus. 
How can I feel the embedding matrix only for words in my_vocabulary?
In addition, I would like to have the flexibility that if my word does not exist in the Google's word2vec to be filled with zeros.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gensim.models.Word2Vec` to build your custom w2v model.

```
sentences = [['cats', 'can', 'not', 'fly'], ['dogs','cant' 'drive']]
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)
```

Reference: https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can fill your embedding matrix using the following code:

```
import gensim

# Load Google's pre-trained Word2Vec model.
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('path/to/bin', binary=True)

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(my_vocabulary), 300))

for index,word in enumerate(my_vocabulary):
    try:
        # update embedding matrix using Google's pretrained model
        embedding_matrix[index] = model.mv[word] 
    except:
        # when word isn't found in pretrained model, we keep the embedding matrix unchanged at that index (assigned to zero)
        pass
```

Further, you can explore ways to initialize your out of vocabulary words to some values other than zero.

Comment: "Further, you can explore ways to initialize your out of vocabulary words to some values other than zero" Could you give some more info or source on this. Never heard it before. Thanks

Comment: @A.Papa Initializing Out of Vocabulary(OOV) words with zeros wouldn't be a good idea. It's better to ignore unknown words than supply a random-vector, like you were initializing them to zero. But if you have a corpus with many such examples of an OOV words, you can train your own vector for it. Or there are alternatives like [Facebook's FastText](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText#obtaining-word-vectors-for-out-of-vocabulary-words) variant of word2vec. It can also synthesize often-better-than-random vectors for previously unseen words due to shared word-roots. Hope that helps.